# How to decode Image with multiple QR images in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, image-processing, qr-code, node-modules

I am using jsQR for decoding and Jimp for making the Bitmap data from the given image. when I do try an image with single QR code jsQR it is giving the decoded value. But image with two QR codes, it is returning null. So How can we do decode the image which is having two QR images?

**NodeJS Code:**

```
const fs = require('fs');
const Jimp = require("jimp");
const jsQR = require("jsqr");

var buffer = fs.readFileSync("file path comes here");
Jimp.read(buffer, async function(err, image) {
  const value = jsQR(image.bitmap.data, image.bitmap.width, image.bitmap.height);
  console.log(value.data)
})
```

**Single QR code Image Example with response:**
[image]
response:

```
 { binaryData:
       [ 104,
         116,
         116,
         112,
         115,
         .... ],
      data: 'https://diksha.gov.in/dial/2C2N18',
      chunks:
       [ { type: 'byte',
           bytes: [Array],
           text: 'https://diksha.gov.in/dial' },
         { type: 'alphanumeric', text: '/2C2N18' } ],
      location:
       { topRightCorner: { x: 353.6252565707135, y: 31.37474342928661 },....
 }
```

**Multiple QR codes Image Example with Response:**
[image]

reponse:

```
null
```

Please let me know, if there is any suggestion.

***Thanks for the future response :)***

Comment: This is an open issue as of now. But I see some recent activity there. https://github.com/cozmo/jsQR/issues/24

Comment: Thanks for the information

Comment: If it's certain that the codes will be aligned in a grid, you can crop the image accordingly and then pass each image into it.

Comment: Thanks @UdayrajDeshmukh . Its great idea. I will do try this.